# Accelerometer data problems in WP7.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, xna-4.0

I am making a simple game to implement the accelerometer data, the idea is that the accelerometer data determines the acceleration of the ball that is wondering aimlessly on the screen, the ball doesn't fall off the edges of the screen, so whenver it hits a wall, the speed is reversed.

The problem is sometimes the ball behavior is very nice and as expected, other times, it jumps on and off spots on screen, I cannot track the problem, here's the code:

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D BallTexture;
    Vector2 BallPosition;
    Vector2 BallSpeed;
    Vector2 BallAcc;

    float CoFriction = 0.15F;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";


        //set to full screen
        graphics.IsFullScreen = true;

        // Frame rate is 30 fps by default for Windows Phone.
        TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);

        // Extend battery life under lock.
        InactiveSleepTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {

        //speed,position,acceleration
        BallSpeed = Vector2.Zero;
        BallAcc = Vector2.Zero;
        BallPosition = new Vector2(240,400);


        //Accelerometer
        Accelerometer acc = new Accelerometer();
        acc.ReadingChanged += new EventHandler<AccelerometerReadingEventArgs>(readingChanged);
        acc.Start();

        base.Initialize();
    }

    public void readingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerReadingEventArgs e)
    {

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => handleAccChange(e));
    }
    public void handleAccChange(AccelerometerReadingEventArgs e)
    {
        BallAcc.X = -(float)Math.Round((float)e.Y);
        BallAcc.Y = -(float)Math.Round((float)e.X);

    }
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        BallTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("football2");
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);


    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {

    }


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        BallSpeed += BallAcc;
        BallPosition += BallSpeed;



        //Check Borders
        if (BallPosition.X < 0 || BallPosition.X > 800 - 51)
        {

            if (BallPosition.X < 0)
                BallPosition.X = 5;
            else if (BallPosition.X > 800 - 51)
                BallPosition.X = 800 - 55;
            BallSpeed.X = -BallSpeed.X * CoFriction;

            if (BallPosition.Y < 0 || BallPosition.Y > 480 - 51)
            {

                if (BallPosition.Y < 0)
                    BallPosition.Y = 5;
                if (BallPosition.Y > 480 - 51)
                    BallPosition.Y = 480 - 55;
                BallSpeed.Y = -BallSpeed.Y * CoFriction;

            }
            base.Update(gameTime);
            return;
        }
        if (BallPosition.Y < 0 || BallPosition.Y > 480 - 51)
        {
            BallSpeed.Y = -BallSpeed.Y*CoFriction;
            if (BallPosition.Y < 0)
                BallPosition.Y = 5;
            if (BallPosition.Y > 480 - 51)
                BallPosition.Y = 480 - 55;

            if (BallPosition.X < 0 || BallPosition.X > 800 - 51)
            {
                BallSpeed.X = -BallSpeed.X*CoFriction;
                if (BallPosition.X < 0)
                    BallPosition.X = 5;
                if (BallPosition.X > 800 - 51)
                    BallPosition.X = 800 - 55;

            }
            base.Update(gameTime);
            return;
        }




        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(BallTexture, BallPosition, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();


        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm a noob in WP7 Developing but VS10 says Accelerometer.ReadingChanged is deprecated and one should use .CurrentValueChanged event. The rest seems pretty much the same. I found that article: 
http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/XNA-for-Silverlight-developers-Part-6-Input-accelerometer.aspx

Just scroll down to 'Some important notes about "Mango"'

Good luck, happy coding